# Definite integral correct?

Tags: calculus

I just took a math test last week and our teacher let us do corrections. I got $\frac{5}{8}$ points on this question and I'm not sure why, did I do something wrong?

Carefully present the computation of the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^n  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left.\Big(2\sqrt{x}\Big)\right|_0^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2\sqrt{n} = \infty \implies \text{Divergence}$$

Comment: Seems OK to me.  But you should probably talk to your teacher to find out what was objectionable about it.  It's conceivable that upon further review, nothing at all will be found objectionable about it.

Comment: Did you write $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-1/2}\ dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{0}^{b} x^{-1/2}\ dx$ instead of $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-1/2}\ dx = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} x^{-1/2}\ dx$? If so, that might explain the lost points despite the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first note that both bounds are problematic, so your integral should be split as
$$
\lim_{a\to0}\int_{a}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx
$$
and
$$
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_1^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx
$$
Both limits must exist and be finite in order that the given integral converges.

The first limit is finite, the second one isn't.

If the function to integrate had been $1/x^2$, your method would have given a very wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems correct to me. I would talk to the teacher about this one... the math you post is correct, but perhaps your teacher was looking for something else, or there was misinterpretation on either your side or your teacher's side.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, the integrand is improper at $0$ as well as at $\infty$.  So you should consider $$\int_{x=0}^\infty x^{-1/2} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 x^{-1/2} \, dx + \int_{x=1}^\infty x^{-1/2} \, dx,$$ demonstrate that the first integral on the RHS is finite, and then demonstrate that the second is infinite.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show divergence at $\infty$ ?